# Retrieve an array from a php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help me out..

**example.html**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {dat: a, pata: id},
      url: 'select.php',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data.length); 
      }
    });
</script>
```

**select.php**

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "empty_spot";


    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    $q1="select * from seats";

    $i = 0;
    $all_chairs = array();

    $query = mysqli_query($connection,$q1);

    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $all_chairs[$i] = $obj["status"];
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode($all_chairs);

?>
```

Comment: What is the actual question? What's your problem?

Comment: I have put the <script> tag in html, it didn't appear here in code, don't know why...

Comment: In your javascript, what's 'a'? whats `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here 
make it `data:{"dat":a,"pata":id}` . If a and id are variable define it else put them too in quotes